# HexLife: Turing complete?

Tags: turing-machines, decidability, cellular-automata

Has anything "interesting" been discovered if one generalizes Conway's Life
on a rectangular grid to a hexagonal grid?
There have been several explorations of [Life on a hexagonal grid](https://conwaylife.com/wiki/Hexagonal_neighbourhood).
In particular:

> ***Q***. Is Life on a hexagonal grid
> Turing complete, as is [Life on a rectangular grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)?

Comment: You have to detail which rules you take... for example do you take the same rules as in this paper https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1811/1811.12387.pdf ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: Thanks for the reference. I would be interested in any reasonable set of rules. In the Discussion section, that paper says "it does not appear feasible for the universal constructor."